# "No state in response" error with OIDC_CLIENT and angularJS

Tags: identityserver3

I am trying to replace the old oidc-token-manager with oidc-client in my angular app, but I keep getting this error
"No state in response", I have look at  brockallen sample to learn how to use it, but not luck so far.
Here is what I have in my service.

```
var config = {
                client_id: "myClient"
                , redirect_uri: "http://127.0.0.1:51899/callback.html"
                , response_type: "id_token token"
                , scope: "openid profile test"
                , authority: "https://localhost:44369"
            };
            var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
```

and similar thing on my callback page.

This is what I have in my mainController

```
var tokenManager = {
            mgr: {}
        };
        tokenManager.mgr = oidc.tokenManager();
        startSigninMainWindow(tokenManager);

        function startSigninMainWindow(tokenManager) {
            tokenManager.mgr.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
                var data = user.state.some;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err); // err:'No state in response'
            });
        }
```

Could any body tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.
PS: BTW, I don't even get to see the login screen in the Identity Server any more

Comment: Enable logging and see where the error comes from.

Comment: I have logging enabled, but it doesn't say much. UserManager.signingRedirectCalback, RedirectNavigator.url , _signingEnd, OidcClient.processingSigningResponse, UrlUtility.parseUrlFragment this is all the information in the logging.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this - am having the exact same issue

Comment: With angular 5.2.8 I had the same issue. I put the line: window.location.hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash); before calling signinRedirectCallback on UserManager. Give it a try. This is a breaking change in Angular 5.2.8 that they started to encode the hash. But I do not really understand the details.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was garbage in the Local Storage. Open the chrome debugger "Application" tab and clear all the **Local** and **Session** storage. Then reload the app.

**NOTE:** as a developer you *need to know* that oidc-client uses session/local storage for a cache. It does **not** refresh the cache if, for example, you change the configuration of your token. You *must* manually clear the storage.

Comment: This was a small piece in a very long puzzle, but thank you for pointing me to the Local and Session storage.

Just to help answer the actual question, it turned out that my Client was sending a "state" param (And it's value was a key to lookup a state object in Local storage), but my Server was not sending the "state" back. And so, "No state in response".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone was calling the `/login` callback route directly from the UI code.  The `/login` route should only be called by the SSO server (Identity Provider, whatever you call it) and never by the UI itself.  So in our `authGuard` we replaced `this.router.navigate(['/login']);` with `this.userManager.signinRedirect();` and it cleared right up.